# Objective C - cellForRowAtIndexPath Cell Never Nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the QuickBlox framework to build a chatting app. Below is the cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

There are some things I'd like to do with each cell only once (like download images), so as I understood, I should add the if (!cell) block to do this.

However, that block never actually fires, even when the tableview is loading for the first time. Why would that be?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   QBChatMessage *message = [[ChatService shared] messagsForDialogId:self.dialog.ID][indexPath.row]; 
   ChatMessageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatMessageCellIdentifier];

   if (!cell) {
   // some things I only want to do once here, such as download images. but it never fires
   }

   [cell configureCellWithMessage:message];
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` won't return `nil` if you used `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Comment: Yep. You could find that in the documentation you know...

Comment: @rmaddy I did use registerClass...is there another way that would allow me to do what I want?

Comment: Sure - remove the use of `registerClass...`. Then you can do what you want in `cellForRow...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will only return `nil` if you didn't register a cell using `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Remove your use of `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` can return `nil` and you can create a new cell and initialize it properly in your `if` statement:

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[ChatMessageTableViewCell alloc] init...]; // use proper init method
    // setup cell as needed for first time
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've always done it by registering the class. this is simple and helped me out

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could perform the one time actions inside the initialiser of the `ChatMessageTableViewCell` class. That way you could keep the behaviour you are used to with registering.